# Is there a way to filter an array of objects using wildcard properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following:

```
const cars = [
   {
      make: 'BMW',
      model: 'E46',
      year: 2002,
   },

   {
      make: 'Toyota',
      model: 'Altis',
      year: 2009,
   },

   {
      make: 'Chevrolet',
      model: 'Camaro',
      year: 1969,
   },

   {
      make: 'Chevrolet',
      model: 'Silverado',
      year: 2002,
   },
];

const filters = [
   {
      type: 'make',
      payload: 'Chevrolet',
   },

   {
      type: 'year',
      payload: 2002,
   },
];
```

How do I `filter` the `cars` using something like the code below?

```
let filteredCars = [];

filters.forEach(filter => filteredCars = cars.filter(car => car.[filter.type] === car.[filter.payload]));
```

Comment: Are the filters OR or AND. Do they need to meet all filters or any of the filters?

Comment: EDIT: since my post is "mostly" code, I meant:

filters.forEach(filter => filteredCars = cars.filter(car => car.[filter.type] === filter.payload));

Comment: @Jack the filters are AND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` and `some` to match any of the filters

```
cars.filter((o) => filters.some((f) => o[f.type] == f.payload))
```

```js
const cars = [ { make: "BMW", model: "E46", year: 2002 }, { make: "Toyota", model: "Altis", year: 2009 }, { make: "Chevrolet", model: "Camaro", year: 1969 }, { make: "Chevrolet", model: "Silverado", year: 2002 }, ];
const filters = [ { type: "make", payload: "Chevrolet" }, { type: "year", payload: 2002 }, ];

res = cars.filter((o) => filters.some((f) => o[f.type] == f.payload));
console.log(res);
```

Or use `filter` and `every` to match *all* of the filters

```
res = cars.filter((o) => filters.every((f) => o[f.type] == f.payload));
```

```js
const cars = [ { make: "BMW", model: "E46", year: 2002 }, { make: "Toyota", model: "Altis", year: 2009 }, { make: "Chevrolet", model: "Silverado", year: 2002 }, { make: "Chevrolet", model: "Camaro", year: 1969 }, ];
const filters = [ { type: "make", payload: "Chevrolet" }, { type: "year", payload: 2002 }, ];

let res = cars.filter((o) => filters.every((f) => o[f.type] == f.payload));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The array still includes other `cars` with the same `model` even if the `year` is filtered out. I failed to mention that the filters are to be AND, as pointed out by @Jack

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EfxWRzV.png

The array length here should be 2 given that the filter includes '2002'

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a method to match all filters let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

First, write a predicate that matches a single car against a single filter.

```
function carMatchesFilter(car, filter) {
  return car[filter.type] === filter.payload;
}
```

If we want to include such cars that match *all* of the filters, we would then write

```
const filteredCars = cars.filter(car =>
  filters.every(filter => carMatchesFilter(car, filter))
);
```

If we want to include such cars that match *any* of the filters, we would then write

```
const filteredCars = cars.filter(car =>
  filters.some(filter => carMatchesFilter(car, filter))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easy when we use `lodash` functions.

```
filteredCards = cars;
filters.forEach(function(element) {
    filteredCards = _.filter(filteredCards, function(o) {
        return o[element.type] == element.payload;
    });
});
```

I hope it would be helpful.